# Creating an event number column based on records separated by certain events

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**I HAVE THE FOLLOWING DATAFRAME**

[image: input dataframe]

**I AM TRYING TO GET TO THIS DATAFRAME**

[image]

**My code is here (includes my attempted solution)**

```
import pandas as pd



# Data

myInput = {'name': ['TOM','TOM','TOM','TOM','TOM','TOM','TOM'], 
'fruit': ['apple','apple','orange','orange','apple','orange','apple']}
df_input = pd.DataFrame(data=myInput)
print(df_input.head())



# Attempted Solution

df_input['eventID'] = (df_input['fruit'] != df_input['fruit'].shift(1)).astype(int).cumsum()
print(df_input.head())
```

**My attempted solution** (Note, removing even numbers in the eventID column isn't a solution. Sometimes the fruit list may begin with orange.)

[image]

Thank you all for your help. I am pretty stumped on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we can do assign a new value for help , then `groupby` both columns

```
df['out'] = range(len(df))
df['out'] = df.groupby(['name', 'fruit'])['out'].apply(lambda x: x.diff().ne(1).cumsum()).where(df.fruit.eq('apple'))
df
Out[252]: 
  name   fruit  id  out
0  TOM   apple   0  1.0
1  TOM   apple   1  1.0
2  TOM  orange   2  NaN
3  TOM  orange   3  NaN
4  TOM   apple   4  2.0
5  TOM  orange   5  NaN
6  TOM   apple   6  3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `groupby().ngroup()` on the cumsum of negate condition:

```
s = df_input.fruit.eq('apple')

df_input['enventId'] = s[s].groupby((~s).cumsum() ).ngroup() +1
```

Output:

```
  name   fruit  eventID
0  TOM   apple      1.0
1  TOM   apple      1.0
2  TOM  orange      NaN
3  TOM  orange      NaN
4  TOM   apple      2.0
5  TOM  orange      NaN
6  TOM   apple      3.0
```